# Sending message to azure IoT hub with x509 certificate authentication

Tags: mqtt, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk, mqtt.js

I am trying to send telemetry messages to Azure IoT Hub using the [npm mqtt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mqtt) library, instead of using **Azure Nodejs SDK/Library**.

I am using X509 certificate authentication. The device connection is working fine when I use azure Nodejs SDK/Library and I am able to send telemetry messages.

When trying to use the MQTT library, it is saying unauthorized.

```
const mqtt = require("mqtt");
const fs = require('fs');

let options = {
  cert: fs.readFileSync("device-cert.pem", "utf-8").toString(),
  key: fs.readFileSync("device-cert.key", "utf-8").toString(),
  passphrase: '1234',
  clientId: "device-003",
  username: "ih-iot-sample-001.azure-devices.net/device-003/?api-version=2021-04-12",
}
let client = mqtt.connect(
  "mqtts://ih-iot-sample-001.azure-devices.net:8883",
  options
);
client.on("connect", function () {
    console.log("connected");
});
client.on("error", (err) => {
  console.log(err);
  process.exit(0)
});
```

**Error :**

> Connection refused: Not authorized

Answer (score 0):

The **clientid** and the **deviceId** in the **username** were wrong. That's why I got this error